# Hollow rectangle with 3 methods

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
    int width;
    int height;

    put("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
    width = input.nextInt();

    put("Enter the height of the rectangle: ");
    height = input.nextInt();

    rectangle( height, width );
}

public static void put(String text){
    System.out.print( text );
}

public static void put(String text, int Number){
    int plus;
    for ( plus = Number ; plus >=  1; plus-- ){
        System.out.print( text);
    }
}

public static void rectangle(int height, int width){
    int column;
    int row;

    for ( row = 1; row <= height; row++){
        put("*", width);
        put("\n");
    }
}
```

i want to create a hollow rectangle, and i have to modify only by the rectangle () method

```
******
*    *
*    *
******
```

It should be something like this ^

Any idea?

edit one

I find a way to add the first row and the last row with this code

```
public static void rectangle(int height, int width) {
    int column;
    int row;

    for (row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
        if (row == 1 || row == height) {
            put("*", width);
        }
        else {
            put(" ");
        }
        put("\n");
    }
}
```

I think that now I should control the width so I can print the two missed stars in the first and last column. I couldn't find the way to connect the rectangle method with second put method.

Any ideas please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem in the code you posted?

Comment: its code print a rectangle stars and i want it to be a hollow rectangle by modifying the last method which is rectangle(); . what i know is i have to put an if statement.

Comment: And which part of the code doing that confuses you? What did you do to try and fix it?

Comment: @jame that is because you've used `put("*", width);` on each iteration, you only need to use that on the first and last row.

Comment: please check the comment edit.

Comment: @jame yes, you're right, you need an `if` statement. You can do this using an `if...else` statement that checks if the current iteration is for the first/last row.

Comment: *"any idea ?"* Yes. modify the `rectangle()` method, like your *assignment* said. Don't just dump the assignment on us. We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Additionally it looks like all the even rows are blank so you will need to account for that as well.(Hint: use modulus)

Comment: i did't dump the assignment on you. i tried many times and i put the if...else statement . but it always show 

something like this 

******
  ******

Comment: How are we supposed to know? You didn't say that, explain that, or show that.

Comment: Please don't shout

Comment: What are you talking about? Who's shouting?

Answer (score 2):

Try thinking of this in terms of rows and columns. In the first and last rows (`row = 1` or `row = height`), you have a * in each column. In any other row, you have a `*` in the first and last column and a space in the rest of the columns.

As pointed out in the comments, it looks like you're putting `*` in each column unconditionally, but as described above you only want to do that for the first and last row.

**Edit:** If you want to include a blank line on even rows, here's a hint: the definition of an "even" number is "exactly divisible by 2" - think about how you could implement that in Java.

Comment: Also, even rows are blank(have no stars), so the user will have to account for that.

Comment: @user2023608 I don't think there are any blank rows, the example contains 4 rows and each row has starts on it (6 or 2 stars).

Comment: @Titus Hmm I can't tell if it is a blank row or just how it gets printed out lol.  Would have been better if an example input was included.